# Subnet delegated prefix on SRX

Tags: ipv6, juniper, srx, dhcpv6

I configured a Juniper SRX firewall to receive IPv6 prefix from upstream router:

```
        family inet6 {
            dhcpv6-client {
                client-type statefull;
                client-ia-type ia-pd;
                update-router-advertisement {
                    interface vlan.20;
                    interface vlan.30;
                    interface vlan.40;
                }
                client-identifier duid-type duid-ll;
                req-option dns-server;
                req-option domain;
            }
        }
```

Received IPv6 prefix is a /56 address pool

```
Client IP Prefix:             xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:x000::/56
```

For `vlan.20`. `vlan.30` and `vlan.40`, I need to further subnet the received prefix to /64. Is there anyway to do this?

BTW: In Cisco equipment, the above task can be done with

```
ipv6 address prefix-from-provider 0:0:0:01::/64 eui-64
```

at interface configuration.